# Plotly: How to update the start date and end date in DatePickerRange automatically based on a chained dropdown value?

Tags: python, datepicker, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to update the start date and end date automatically for DatePickerRange in the callback where  the input is a prior dropdown's value. I have 2 chained dropdowns where I'm doing the same for updating the options of the second dependent dropdown. I tried doing the same for datepickerRange but I can't seem to find a way where I can return the start date and end date from def here:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='date_choice', component_property='start_date'),
    Output(component_id='date_choice', component_property='end_date'),
    Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value'))
def get_options(date_choice):
    dff = df[df.date2 == date_choice]
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dff['date2']]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import dash
import datetime as datetime
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13},
               'Technology': {0: '4G', 1: '4G', 2: 'SM', 3: '5G', 4: 'SM', 5: '4G', 6: 'SM', 7: '5G', 8: '2G', 9: 'SM', 10: '5G', 11: 'SM', 12: 'SM', 13: '4G'},
               'SystemRelease': {0: 'lte22', 1: 'lte22', 2: 'umts22', 3: '5G22', 4: 'umts22A', 5: 'lte18A', 6: 'umts6A', 7: '5G22A', 8: '2G18', 9: 'L22B', 10: '5G22A', 11: 'umts22B', 12: 'L22A', 13: 'lte18A'},
               'Date': {0: '27.09.2022', 1: '26.09.2022', 2: '25.09.2022', 3: '25.09.2022', 4: '24.09.2022', 5: '23.09.2022', 6: '23.09.2022', 7: '23.09.2022', 8: '20.09.2022', 9: '22.09.2022', 10: '22.09.2022', 11: '22.09.2022', 12: '22.09.2022', 13: '22.09.2022'},
               'TypeofRelease': {0: 'Normal Update', 1: 'Standard Update', 2: 'Standard Update', 3: 'Maintenance Delivery', 4: 'Delivery', 5: 'Standard Update', 6: 'Normal Update', 7: 'Delivery', 8: 'Standard Update', 9: 'Delivery', 10: 'Delivery', 11: 'Delivery', 12: 'Delivery', 13: 'Standard Update'},
               'Package': {0: '2.5', 1: '0.3', 2: '0.3', 3: '1.1.2', 4: '1.0', 5: '3.0.7', 6: '01.03.2007', 7: '0.2', 8: '2.3', 9: '1.0', 10: '0.5', 11: '1.0', 12: '1.0.6', 13: '6.0'}})


df['date2'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y') for x in df['Date'] ]
df.sort_values(by=['date2'], inplace=True)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.title = "Roadmap"

app.layout = html.Div(

children=[

    html.Div(
        children=[
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.Div(children='Select Technology:', className="menu-title"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='Tech_choice',
                        options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                                 for x in df.Technology.unique()],
                        value='4G',
                        clearable=False,
                        className="dropdown",

                    ), ]),
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.Div(children="Select Release:", className="menu-title"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='release_choice',
                        options=[],
                        clearable=False,
                        className="dropdown",
                    )
                ]
            ),
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.Div(children="Select Date:", className="menu-title"),
                    dcc.DatePickerRange(
                        id="date_choice",
                        min_date_allowed=df.date2.min().date(),
                        max_date_allowed=df.date2.max().date(),
                        start_date=df.date2.min().date(),
                        end_date=df.date2.max().date(),
                    )
                ]
            ),
        ],
        className="menu",
    ),
    html.Div(
        children=[
            html.Div(
                children=dcc.Graph(
                    id='my-graph', config={"displayModeBar": False},
                    # style={'overflowY': 'scroll', 'width': 1000}
                ),
                className="card",
            ),
        ],
        className="wrapper",
    ), ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='release_choice', component_property='options'),
    Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value'))
def get_options(Tech_choice):
    dff = df[df.Technology == Tech_choice]
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dff['SystemRelease'].unique()]

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='options'))
def get_values(release_choice):
    return [k['value'] for k in release_choice][1]

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='date_choice', component_property='start_date'),
    Output(component_id='date_choice', component_property='end_date'),
    Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value'))
def get_options(date_choice):
    dff = df[df.date2 == date_choice]  # doubt
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dff['date2']]


@app.callback(Output(component_id='my-graph', component_property='figure'),
              [Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value')],
              [Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value')],
              [Input(component_id='date_choice', component_property='start_date')],
              [Input(component_id='date_choice', component_property='end_date')], )
def int_gr(release_choice, Tech_choice, start_date, end_date):
    print(Tech_choice)
    print(release_choice)
    dff = df[(df['SystemRelease'] == release_choice) & (df['Technology'] == Tech_choice) & (df['date2'] >= start_date) & (df['date2'] <= end_date)]
    fig = px.scatter(data_frame=dff, x='date2', y='SystemRelease', color="TypeofRelease", text='Package',
                     labels={
                         "SystemRelease": "System Release",
                         "date2": "Date",
                         "TypeofRelease": "Type of Release:"
                     })
    fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12,
                                  line=dict(width=2,
                                            color='DarkSlateGrey')),

                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))
# fig.update_traces(boxpoints='all', jitter=0.8)
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center', mode='markers+text')

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1200,
    height=400)

return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

and a quick glance at the data:
[image]

Comment: @vestland I have added a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871223/plotly-how-to-download-the-plot-as-html-from-the-front-end-dash I will be very grateful if u could have a look and contribute.

Comment: @sleepuPanda Sure thing! I'll take a closer look when I find the time.

Comment: @vestland TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, and I can't guarantee that the resulting app will do exactly what you're aimiing for. But the only error you seem to be making here is:

> The input argument `Tech_choice.value` must be a list or tuple of
> `dash.dependencies.Input`s.

And what this is telling is that your callback has to be set up as:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='release_choice', component_property='options'),
    [Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value')])
```

Instead of:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='release_choice', component_property='options'),
    Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value'))
```

Where the former has `Input` enclosed by square brackets and is therefore an element in a list, while the latter is what you've tried. You're on to something a bit further down where you've got:

```
@app.callback(Output(component_id='my-graph', component_property='figure'),
              [Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value')],
              [Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value')],
              [Input(component_id='date_choice', component_property='start_date')],
              [Input(component_id='date_choice', component_property='end_date')], )
```

But here you've set up your `Input` components as a ***list of lists*** instead of just a list, and so that will fail too. This can all be a bit confusing since `Input` has to be an element of a list, while `Output` does not. But that only applies to cases where your callbacks has a single `Output`. Anyway, if you fix these things. And also take care of what might be indentation errors that only occur in your code sample and not the code you're working with, namely these:

```
    fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12,
                                  line=dict(width=2,
                                            color='DarkSlateGrey')),

                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))
# fig.update_traces(boxpoints='all', jitter=0.8)
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center', mode='markers+text')

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1200,
    height=400)

return fig
```

Then you'll end up with this seemingly working app:

[image]

Now, whether or not this does exactly what you're aiming for isn't easy for me to know, but please let me know how it works out for you!

#### Complete code:

```
import dash
import datetime as datetime
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13},
               'Technology': {0: '4G', 1: '4G', 2: 'SM', 3: '5G', 4: 'SM', 5: '4G', 6: 'SM', 7: '5G', 8: '2G', 9: 'SM', 10: '5G', 11: 'SM', 12: 'SM', 13: '4G'},
               'SystemRelease': {0: 'lte22', 1: 'lte22', 2: 'umts22', 3: '5G22', 4: 'umts22A', 5: 'lte18A', 6: 'umts6A', 7: '5G22A', 8: '2G18', 9: 'L22B', 10: '5G22A', 11: 'umts22B', 12: 'L22A', 13: 'lte18A'},
               'Date': {0: '27.09.2022', 1: '26.09.2022', 2: '25.09.2022', 3: '25.09.2022', 4: '24.09.2022', 5: '23.09.2022', 6: '23.09.2022', 7: '23.09.2022', 8: '20.09.2022', 9: '22.09.2022', 10: '22.09.2022', 11: '22.09.2022', 12: '22.09.2022', 13: '22.09.2022'},
               'TypeofRelease': {0: 'Normal Update', 1: 'Standard Update', 2: 'Standard Update', 3: 'Maintenance Delivery', 4: 'Delivery', 5: 'Standard Update', 6: 'Normal Update', 7: 'Delivery', 8: 'Standard Update', 9: 'Delivery', 10: 'Delivery', 11: 'Delivery', 12: 'Delivery', 13: 'Standard Update'},
               'Package': {0: '2.5', 1: '0.3', 2: '0.3', 3: '1.1.2', 4: '1.0', 5: '3.0.7', 6: '01.03.2007', 7: '0.2', 8: '2.3', 9: '1.0', 10: '0.5', 11: '1.0', 12: '1.0.6', 13: '6.0'}})


df['date2'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y') for x in df['Date'] ]
df.sort_values(by=['date2'], inplace=True)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.title = "Roadmap"

app.layout = html.Div(

children=[

    html.Div(
        children=[
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.Div(children='Select Technology:', className="menu-title"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='Tech_choice',
                        options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                                 for x in df.Technology.unique()],
                        value='4G',
                        clearable=False,
                        className="dropdown",

                    ), ]),
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.Div(children="Select Release:", className="menu-title"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='release_choice',
                        options=[],
                        clearable=False,
                        className="dropdown",
                    )
                ]
            ),
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    html.Div(children="Select Date:", className="menu-title"),
                    dcc.DatePickerRange(
                        id="date_choice",
                        min_date_allowed=df.date2.min().date(),
                        max_date_allowed=df.date2.max().date(),
                        start_date=df.date2.min().date(),
                        end_date=df.date2.max().date(),
                    )
                ]
            ),
        ],
        className="menu",
    ),
    html.Div(
        children=[
            html.Div(
                children=dcc.Graph(
                    id='my-graph', config={"displayModeBar": False},
                    # style={'overflowY': 'scroll', 'width': 1000}
                ),
                className="card",
            ),
        ],
        className="wrapper",
    ), ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='release_choice', component_property='options'),
    [Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value')])
def get_options(Tech_choice):
    dff = df[df.Technology == Tech_choice]
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dff['SystemRelease'].unique()]

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value'),
    [Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='options')])
def get_values(release_choice):
    return [k['value'] for k in release_choice][1]

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='date_choice', component_property='start_date'),
    Output(component_id='date_choice', component_property='end_date')],
    [Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value')])
def get_options(date_choice):
    dff = df[df.date2 == date_choice]  # doubt
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dff['date2']]


@app.callback(Output(component_id='my-graph', component_property='figure'),
              [Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='date_choice', component_property='start_date'),
              Input(component_id='date_choice', component_property='end_date')], )
def int_gr(release_choice, Tech_choice, start_date, end_date):
    print(Tech_choice)
    print(release_choice)
    dff = df[(df['SystemRelease'] == release_choice) & (df['Technology'] == Tech_choice) & (df['date2'] >= start_date) & (df['date2'] <= end_date)]
    fig = px.scatter(data_frame=dff, x='date2', y='SystemRelease', color="TypeofRelease", text='Package',
                     labels={
                         "SystemRelease": "System Release",
                         "date2": "Date",
                         "TypeofRelease": "Type of Release:"
                     })
    fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12,
                                  line=dict(width=2,
                                            color='DarkSlateGrey')),

                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))
    # fig.update_traces(boxpoints='all', jitter=0.8)
    fig.update_traces(textposition='top center', mode='markers+text')

    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=False,
        width=1200,
        height=400)

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback and tracking back, I really am grateful @vestland! 
About the code, 
1. I am trying not to take default start date and end date value from the whole date column, but only from the date values of that particular "Release".
2. I am also trying to save the HTML so for that, if there's a possibility to specify the exact start and end date in the code itself? Like in the first dropdown, I specified value='4G', and for second dropdown, I specified return [k['value'] for k in release_choice][1] so that it gets me to the 1st value in 4G, so something similar for dates?